# Angular Generator VSCode Plugin similar to one from Angular Documentation

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In the Angular documentation there is a screenshot referencing an **Angular Generator** in the context menu in Stackblitz. I was hoping to find something similar for VSCode.

After few google searches all I can come up with is an Angular Snippets plugin. Does anyone know how to get the **Angular Generator** option in the context menu?

https://angular.io/start#input

[image]

I am very aware that the cli is probably the preferable method of scaffolding app code, but I was curious if anyone knew how to get this extension because I could see it being useful.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that's a screenshot taken from Stackblitz site

Comment: oh, you're right, I should have noticed that. I wonder if anyone's created something similar?

Comment: https://github.com/nrwl/angular-console/issues/650

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: One reason I'm looking for an extension rather than CLI is I'm trying to create components like 8 directories deep and don't want to have to type out that path every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyrille Tuzi [introduced](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/angular-schematics-cli-commands-in-visual-studio-code-d9a56383f53e) Angular Schematics extension can do exactly what you want

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics

Another extension that can offer similar feature is Angular Console

- https://angularconsole.com/